# C++11 language support in g++ without the library-breaking features of `-std=c++11`

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

Is there a way to tell `g++` to enable the new language features of C++11 without any breaking changes to the standard C++ library due to ABI modifications?

Adding the `-std=c++11` compilation flag tells `g++` to enable both the language and the library features, but object files created this way cannot be safely linked with those that used a different `-std=` setting.  I'd like to be able to use language enhancements like rvalue references, move constructors (for my own classes), and the `auto` keyword in code that's linked against C++03 libraries.

**EDIT:**

I'm interested in having `g++` enable its C++11 *language* features, but I want it to parse, compile, and link against the old C++03 libraries.  I don't want it to use the C++11 version of the standard library.  This means that in my own code, I'll be able to use `auto`, range foreach constructs, rvalue references, etc., but I *won't* be able to use the new C++11 features in the standard C++ library like `std::move` or rvalue-ref enhancements to the STL containers.  The reason for not wanting the C++11 version of the standard library is that the layout of various objects has changed, so it's invalid to link two object files that expect different versions of the standard library into the same binary.

Comment: As long as you don't want linked libraries work with your advanced classes that should work with `-std=c++11`. If you're having problems, you're either asking for too much or are unfortunate enough to have `gcc` version that broke compatibility (I don't remember what version is that, but it did happen at some point).

Comment: I want to be able to use things like `std::map` that are known to be incompatible (http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility), but I want g++ to compile them in C++03 mode while allowing me to use the language features of C++11 in my own code.  The incompatible `std::` symbols are part of my code's interface, so I can't statically link the standard library as a workaround.

Comment: "*The incompatible std:: symbols are part of my code's interface, so I can't statically link the standard library as a workaround.*" If you're talking about a DLL/SO interface, that's something you should *never do*. You doomed yourself with this design decision; time to either face the consequences or fix your interface.

Comment: @Nicol: Why is using data structures from the standard C++ library in a DLL or SO interface bad?

Comment: @MrFooz: Because it leads to your question. It's fine if you are able to recompile both the DLL/SO and its consumer. But if you don't have tight control over both, then you get your problem.

Comment: Judging by this discussion (http://www.mentby.com/Group/gcc-discuss/c98c11-abi-compatibility-for-gcc-47.html) in the GCC mailing list, I'm afraid it's not possible - as of gcc 4.7 at least. Maybe things will change for gcc 4.8.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't enable C++11 language features without C++11 library features (not without editing the libstdc++ headers to remove all the C++11 parts.)

But there aren't many incompatible symbols (as long as you don't use 4.7.0 or 4.7.1 which had an incompatible `std::list`, reverted for 4.7.2) so you probably only need to worry about the `erase()` members of the RB-tree containers. You could ensure the C++11 version of the symbol is defined in your main executable, so that version of the symbol will be used by all code that needs it. Code in other libraries expecting the C++03 versions will ignore the return value, code expecting the C++11 versions will be able to use the return value.

Comment: 1) Does this advice still hold for GCC 4.8? I've read this page https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/Cxx11AbiCompatibility (probably also written by you?), and it lists a few other bits.

Comment: 2) I'm also unsure of what you mean by "ensure the C++11 version of the symbol is defined in your main executable". Thanks!

Comment: @Rob yes it still applies. The wiki page lists some other bits, but as my answer says, the only one likely to cause any problems is `erase()` for RB trees. If the new version of the symbol is in the executable (not some shared library it links to) then that version of the symbol will be used, which will be safe. That avoids the problem of some libraries defining the old (void-returning) symbol and libraries defining the new (iterator-returning) symbol and not knowing which version will get discarded by the linker.

Comment: Ah - great! Thanks for expanding on your original explanation for my benefit. Looks like I needed slightly different words saying exactly the same thing ;) .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know GCC 4.7 and up has ABI modifications. You can try versions below that.

It may also help to use `-std=gnu++11` instead of `-std=c++11`. Why that exactly is I don't know but it worked for me.

Comment: There might be a huge difference between "compiles" and "works" here …

Comment: There are absolutely no ABI differences between `-std=gnu++11` and `-std=c++11`